# Call an excel macro in specific instance of excel in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, memory, out-of-memory, instance

I'm receiving out of resources errors in 32-bit Excel 365 (64-bit remedies the problem but our IT won't allow it for the number of users that would use this book, so I'm stuck with 32-bit). I have plenty of RAM so I'm trying to split the two workbooks into different instances to allow more memory allocation (if this is a bad strategy I'd be happy to know why/alternatives!).

My set-up has two workbooks, Workbook A opens Workbook B and Workbook B runs the heavy lifting code and then transfers the data back to Workbook A in value format.

Excel Instance 1: Workbook A

Excel Instance 2: Workbook B

I want WkbA (open in Excel Instance 1) to call a macro on WrkB open in Excel Instance 2. I wrote the code below to try this.

```
Dim WkbB As Object
Set WkbB = New Excel.Application
With WkbB
    .Visible = True
    .Workbooks.Open "P:\Root\WorkbookB.xlsm", True, False
End With

Application.Run "'WkbB.xlsm'!Main"
```

At the 'End With' line, the Code opens WkbA and WrkB in two separate Excel Instances as I want

Excel Instance 1: WrkA

Excel Instance 2: WrkB

But at the Application.Run line excel opens WrkB again in instance 1

Excel Instance 1: WrkA & WrkB

Excel Instance 2: WrkB

Instead of calling the Main subroutine in Instance 2 WorkbookB.

Comment: When you say referencing do you mean as in excel formulae or in vba code? Formula-wise WrkB is not referencing WrkA, if you can provide examples I would be happy to try and remove all references and see if this fixes it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Application.Run "'WkbB.xlsm'!Main"
```

to

```
WrkB.Run "'WorkbookB.xlsm'!Main"
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I love easy answers :)